# AWS Personalize: How to capture "returning" or "unselecting" items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, amazon-personalize

I am building an application where I want to update the recommendations "live", ie every time a user adds an item to their cart. I can do this by calling the personalize-events.put-event api. However, what if they remove the item from their cart. There is no delete-event api. Another similar use case I can think of is if the user returns the item.

Comment: I have an idea. Tell me if you think it's dumb. But I noticed that EventType and EventValue can be used to filter interactions out of training. And from what I can tell, these fields are ignored when making predictions. So my idea is that each time the user chooses a new product, we make make a fiat-id for that user and call put-events with all the items that the user has ever chosen. We record these at EventType="Clicked". Once checked-out, we attribute the new purchases to the real user with eventType="Bought". When we train, we only train on bought, i.e. we filter out the "clicked" events.

Comment: Those "Clicked" events still provide useful signal to the model of user intent/interest and should be included in training. In addition, for most sites, there aren't enough "Bought" events across all users but there are plenty of "Clicked" events. Training on both often produces a better model. I suggest starting there and evaluating results before adding this complexity.

Comment: Ok but training doesn't train on eventtype as I understand it so it will regard bought and clicked events as equal. If we wanted to include this as a feature, should we also include a metadata field that duplicated eventtype so that the model could learn the difference between bought and clicked events?

Comment: Event types can be used for filtering interactions at training time (as you noted) and are included as features in the model. If multiple event types are included, they are equally weighted. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483117/13815548) for related info.